# Cannot push minecart

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to create a wheat farm using a minecart that goes back and forth below dirt blocks that have planted seeds.

1. A minecart with a chest does not fit in a 1m gap, should it do that?
2. I cannot make the minecart bounce when it comes to an end.
3. I cannot push the minecart, since I cannot climb inside it (it is holding a chest).

How do I solve those issues?

Comment: Have you tried powered rails?

Comment: Should I put the minecarft on that rail and then push it?

Comment: What do u mean trying to make the minecart "bounce"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I am aware, no. It is slightly taller than 1 block.

Just quick info on powered rails for the next two points.: Any motion at all causes the powered rail to have an effect on the minecart.

2. Bouncing is done by putting a powered rail at the end of the track, followed by a block. The slight bit of backward momentum "activates" the powered rail, causing it to go to full speed in the other direction.
3. By pushing the minecart slightly with your body while on a powered rail, the minecart's movement "activates" the powered rail, causing it to go to full speed in that direction.

Comment: What if there are no powered rails but only booster tracks (Railcraft)?

Comment: The booster tracks in Railcraft are renamed versions of the powered rail. Everything still applies.